# Mapbox - Get region from autocomplete result

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can I get region from the selected result from autocomplete?

From the result I am getting, there is 3rd object named region but actually it is department not region.

Here is the example address:

```
54b route de brie, 91800 Brunoy, France
```

Mapbox is giving me: **Essonne** // Its department not region

But actually its: **Ile-de-France**

How do I get the correct region?

Here is my working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/rv085oL1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information isn't included. But if you just need your site to work in France, it would be straightforward to include a lookup table mapping from département to région, using the last two characters of the `short_code`. Here's one: https://gist.github.com/SiamKreative/f1074ed95507e69d08a0

```
"regions": {
        "alsace": [67, 68],
        "aquitaine": [40, 47, 33, 24, 64],
        "auvergne": [43, 3, 15, 63],
        "basse-normandie": [14, 61, 50],
        "bourgogne": [21, 58, 71, 89],
        "bretagne": [29, 35, 22, 56],
        "centre": [45, 37, 41, 28, 36, 18],
        "champagne-ardenne": [10, 8, 52, 51],
        "corse": ["2b", "2a"],
        "franche-compte": [39, 25, 70, 90],
        "haute-normandie": [27, 76],
        "languedoc-roussillon": [48, 30, 34, 11, 66],
        "limousin": [19, 23, 87],
        "lorraine": [55, 54, 57, 88],
        "midi-pyrennees": [46, 32, 31, 12, 9, 65, 81, 82],
        "nord-pas-de-calais": [62, 59],
        "pays-de-la-loire": [49, 44, 72, 53, 85],
        "picardie": [2, 60, 80],
        "poitou-charentes": [17, 16, 86, 79],
        "provences-alpes-cote-dazur": [4, 5, 6, 13, 84, 83],
        "rhones-alpes": [38, 42, 26, 7, 1, 74, 73, 69],
        "ile-de-france": [77, 75, 78, 93, 92, 91, 95, 94]
    },
```

Comment: you mean I should use result.result.context[2].short_code ?

Comment: This short code information is not always available.

Comment: What's an example where it's missing?

Comment: Try Paris, France, or just Paris please